# Generated Google Protocol Buffer classes have unused fields and are over 2000 lines

Tags: java, maven, serialization, protocol-buffers

As the title says, I wanted to try Google protocol buffers but got stuck on compiling classes from .proto file. I am not sure how should generated class look like and is it normal that it contains 2500 lines.

This is maven project and I have included following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and  protoc.exe is in same directory with .proto files.

I am following examples from [google docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial?hl=hr), however when I try to compile the `addressbook.proto`, generated class has over 2500 lines and unused fields such as the: `int mutable_bitField0_ = 0;`

The generated code looks very odd to me with stuff like this inside:

```
 com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.InternalDescriptorAssigner assigner =
        new com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor.    InternalDescriptorAssigner() {
          public com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry assignDescriptors(
              com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor root) {
            descriptor = root;
            return null;
          }
```

Should generated classes look like this or am I doing something wrong?

As a note, used java version is 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the generated code is very large and very ugly. This is typical for generated code. Every field declaration in the `.proto` file turns into half a dozen or more methods each of which is several lines, plus lines of code to serialize, parse, clear, etc. 2500 lines is actually very small for protobuf generated code.

The code generator is not very smart -- it's basically a bunch of print statements -- so it often produces ugly code, and sometimes it will even generate boilerplate that it doesn't end up using.

You really aren't expected to look at the generated code. :)

Comment: Ah this is contrary to XSD generated classes which are in form of java Beans. What worries me is compiler warning for unused fields, i am a bit skeptic about API which gives me compiler warnings O_O.

Comment: @user3360241 Compiler warnings do seem like a bug. Perhaps you should file an issue.